# Убрать скролл страницы

Tags: html, вёрстка, css, прокрутка

Собственно [вот](http://jsfiddle.net/9FsGN/).

Как сделать так, чтобы зеленый квадрат не влиял на скролл страницы?

UPD:

Опишу задачу. Сайт фиксированной ширины (состоит из одной колонки) `960px`. Внутри одной из страниц есть содержимое шириной более `960px`, которое должно выравниваться по левому краю основной колонки и уходить вправо за `960px` не вызывая собой скролл страницы. Предложите варианты верстки, если таковые есть

UPD:

Колонка в `960px` выравнивается по центру.

Comment: overflow-x: hidden;

а это нормально что у вас внутренний элемент больше внешнего ?

Comment: eicto, фишка в том, что зелный квадрат должен быть виден. то есть выходить за рамки страницы, не образуя скролла.
p.s. это задумка дизайнера

Comment: @Heleg а с каких пор дизайнер управляет разметкой верстки ? 

[`body {overflow: hidden;}`](http://jsfiddle.net/9FsGN/)

Comment: обновил вопрос, подробнее описал, чтобы было понятно, при чем тут дизайнер и разметка

Comment: всё, вопрос решил. eicto, сделай свой каммент про body ответом, я его помечу правильным. спасибо

Answer (score 2):

сделайте

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

или можно всё обернуть элементом с width: 100% и overflow: hidden

Comment: Может, всё-таки `overflow-x: hidden;`? Скролл вниз может понадобиться.

Comment: а-да опечатался :)